# Алгоритм логики игры

Tags: алгоритм, логика, разработка-игр

На каком принципе можно разработать логику игры [такого](http://jackline.ru/games/arkadnie/bloki/blocks.html) типа? Можно ли поиск решения (при условии, что оно всегда существует) свести к какому-либо известному алгоритму? Или к поиску пути в графе например?

Comment: @shatal,
Умение есть, нет понимания принципа. Принцип на пальцах можно? Я не понимаю из чего граф построить, что будет вершинами, что ребрами, нужны ли веса и прочее... Отсюда возникают множество глупых вопросов... При уберании 1 группы кубиков придётся перестраивать весь граф? т.к. -все- большинство фигур выше группы по которой кликнули перестроются... Для чего толда нам этот граф, если его после каждого хода нужно строить заново? Для поиска следующего лучшего хода? На каком основании он лучший? и прочие глупые вопросы

Comment: @Isaev Поиск с помощью графа полным перебором — это **общий подход**. А вы уже спрашиваете про оптимизацию: как сэкономить память за счёт эффективного кодирования состояния, как оптимизировать время поиска с помощью эвристик и так далее. Здесь надо проявить фантазию.

Comment: @Discord, я сделал оценку поля, разбил его на "фигуры" и отдельные лишние элементы, добавил немного к эвристике, чтобы заведомо неправильные возможные ходы отсеивались до перебора. Простым грубым перебором реализовал, но мне не нравится время, потому думаю об оптимизации и возможности перехода к графам (ибо тут наверняка слабое место именно в поиске и при росте поля очень падает время решения). и тут возникает вопрос, как

Comment: @Isaev Ну вот об этом и надо написать в вопросе: что сделали, как сделали, привести код, объяснить проблемы и так далее; не повредит и описать игру словесно, а не только ссылкой с текстом "такого". Вы же предлагаете всем заняться решением этой задачки с нуля. Даже если желающие найдутся, это будет не самый эффективный способ.

Comment: @Discord, мне не нужно реализаций, расскажите о возможности применять граф для решения задачи в теории. Как свести данную задачу к решению с помощью поиска в графе? Что в данном случае есть вершина? Я не под тем углом смотрю, т.к. представляю каждую "фигуру" вершиной, одна удаляется - всё рушится и граф перестраивается заново... в этом тупик

Answer (score 3):

**Вершина графа — состояние игры.** В данном случае самым простым представлением будет массив NxN, где каждое число — индекс цвета квадратика на поле.

**Ребро графа — ход в игре.** В данном случае самым простым представлением будет пара чисел (X,Y) (или объединённый индекс Z=Y*N+X), который означает нажимаемый квадратик.

Ваша задача:

1. Уменьшить количество разбираемых ходов, например, не рассматривать нажатие на соседние квадратики одного цвета как разные ходы.
2. Если возможно, рассматривать в последнюю очередь невыгодные ходы, например, уничтожение только двух клеток, которые не приводят к появлению новых выгодных ходов (это может отсечь хитрые стратегии, надо быть осторожным).
3. Оптимизировать различными способами, например, не рассматривать одинаковые состояния отдельно.

Comment: Так представить понятнее, спасибо. 1 и 2 у меня уже есть, в 3 там есть над чем подумать, когда **Вершина графа — состояние игры** почему бы конечно и не отсечь одинаковые состояния) Сразу появилось несколько идей возможных оптимизаций в старых проектах. Но тогда возникает вопрос: как искать в графе, которого нет? мы же его достраиваем после каждого хода, а когда нужное **состояние игры** достигнуто, мы это увидим на этапе построения и уже не нужно ничего искать. Для чего тогда граф?

Comment: @Isaev Это условно граф, умозрительный. В коде его строить не обязательно. Очереди с приоритетами и цикла может быть достаточно. Просто при таком решении вам понадобится добавить ссылки между состояниями, чтобы восстановить путь решения, вот вам и граф.

Comment: @shatal, Discord описал обычное дерево решений, в котором ноды - состояния системы, и нужно выбрать оптимальный путь в этом дереве. Это область довольно изучена, как и оптимизации для нее.

Comment: @Discord, это грустно тогда, значит у меня так и реализовано... Получается снова брут. Получается оптимизировать поиск можно исключительно эвристикой? 

Состояния игры можно даже не хранить, кстати... Будет достаточно массива контрольных сумм, для отсечения повторных состояний и эффективного поиска по нему

Comment: @shatal, ввиду вышеприведённых доводов хотелось бы таки услышать и ваш ответ

Comment: @shatal, а конкретика будет или только махание руками?

Answer (score 2):

В целом поиск решения в играх типа Clickomania представляет нетривиальную задачу.

- Для поля с одним столбцом, поиск конкретного решения за линейное время для двух цветов и за полиномиальное время для большего количества цветов.
- Уже для двух столбцов и пяти цветов или пяти столбцов и трех цветов, определение наличия решения является NP-полной задачей.

Таким образом в общем случае поможет только полный перебор дерева решений + оптимизации и эвристики.

Если есть академический интерес можно почитать исследование по данной теме (осторожно, зубодробительный CS): http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0107031v1.pdf

Comment: За материал отдельное спасибо, этот мне не попадался ещё по этой теме

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически да. Это игра на ациклическом графе. Состояние - игровое поле. Проблема в том, что оно большое и может оказаться недостаточно памяти для сохранения результатов для конкретного поля, либо времени для перебора.